# asyncpg fetch feedback (python)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I have been using psycopg2 to manage items in my PostgreSQL database.  Recently someone suggested that I could improve my database transactions by using asyncio and asyncpg in my code. I have looked around Stack Overflow and read though the documentation for examples.  I have been able to create tables and insert records, but I haven't been able to get the execution feedback that I desire.

For example in my psycopg2 code, I can verify that a table exists or doesn't exist prior to inserting records.

```
def table_exists(self, verify_table_existence, name):
    '''Verifies the existence of a table within the PostgreSQL database'''
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(verify_table_existence, name)

        answer = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]

        if answer == True:
            print('The table - {} - exists'.format(name))
            return True
        else:
            print ('The table - {} - does NOT exist'.format(name))
            return False

    except Exception as error:

        logger.info('An error has occurred while trying to verify the existence of the table {}'.format(name))
        logger.info('Error message: {}').format(error)
        sys.exit(1)
```

I haven't been able to get the same feedback using asyncpg. How do I accomplish this?

```
import asyncpg
import asyncio

async def main():
conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

answer = await conn.fetch('''
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM   pg_tables
WHERE  schemaname = 'public'
AND    tablename = 'test01'
); ''')

await conn.close()

#####################
# the fetch returns
# [<Record exists=True>]
# but prints 'The table does NOT exist'
#####################

if answer == True:
    print('The table exists')   
else:
    print('The table does NOT exist')


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: You used `fetchone()[0]` with psycopg2, but just `fetch(...)` with asyncpg. The former will retrieve the first column of the first row, while the latter will retrieve a whole list of rows. Being a list, it doesn't compare as equal to `True`. Try using `answer = await conn.fetchval(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: Glad to hear! I've now reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `fetchone()[0]` with psycopg2, but just `fetch(...)` with asyncpg. The former will retrieve the first column of the first row, while the latter will retrieve a whole list of rows. Being a list, it doesn't compare as equal to `True`.

To fetch a single value from a single row, use something like `answer = await conn.fetchval(...)`.